# Delete vector class member

Tags: c++, class, vector, destructor, member

I have a class A with a member which is a vector of object pointers of another class B

```
class A
{
    std::vector<B*> m_member_A
```

`m_member_A` is populated by creating objects of B by using `new` operator

```
B* b1 = new B;
m_member_A.push_back(b1);
```

In A's destructor, is the following correct to free up everything?

```
A::~A()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m_member_A.size(); ++i)
    {
        delete m_member_A[i];
    }

    m_member_A.clear();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it, and practically the only way to do it before c++11. In c++11 you can just use vector<unique_ptr<B>> and it will free automatically

Comment: _'In A's destructor, is the following correct to free up everything?'_ Yes, it's correct. Why aren't you check up this yourself using a good memory leak detection tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: It looks OK. Is there a reason that you think it's not correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct, as long as you also have a correct copy constructor and copy-assignment operator per the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722). Note that the `clear()` is redundant, since the vector's destructor will release its memory.

By why are you messing around with pointers and `new`? Why not follow the Rule of Zero, and use `vector<B>`, or `vector<unique_ptr<B>>` if you need pointers for polymorphism? Then you shouldn't need to worry about a destructor, copy constructor or copy-assignment operator at all; and you'll get move semantics as a bonus.

Comment: @Mike Seymour Should I check for null pointer before `delete m_member_A[i]`, just to be safe?

Comment: @ontherocks: No, it's safe to give `delete` a null pointer; it will do nothing with it.

Comment: @Mike Seymour. Thanks. If `m_member_A` was a `std::map<int, string>`, and that was the only member of A, would I need to implement A's destructor like `A::~A(){ m_member_A.clear(); }` or this is redundant too? If it is redundant then I guess the default destructor would suffice.

Comment: @ontherocks: Indeed, that's redundant. You should never need to do anything when destroying a properly designed class; that's the whole point of having a destructor.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it's correct… yet it is not sufficient.**

You will also need to deep-copy the container whenever your `A` is copied.

If you can use smart pointers inside the vector, then so much the better. Just be clear in your mind and in your code about who owns what.

Answer (score 3):

Almost

If you construct (allocate) elements of B in the constructor of A and some B is throwing an exception you have a memory leak (unless it is caught in the constructor of A where deletion of B's is done)

And the usual rule of three.

Some illustration might be (please adjust MAKE_FAILURE to 0 or 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

#define MAKE_FAILURE 0

static unsigned count;
const unsigned ExceptionThreshold = 3;
struct B {
    B() { if(ExceptionThreshold <= count++) throw std::runtime_error("Sorry"); }
    ~B() { std::cout << "Destruct\n"; }
};

struct A
{
    std::vector<B*> v;
    A()
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < ExceptionThreshold + MAKE_FAILURE; ++i)
            v.push_back(new B);
    }

    ~A()
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            delete v[i];
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Also you get into the terrain of shallow and deep copies (as mentioned by @
Lightness Races in Orb)

Answer (score 2):

This is correct way to free memory of your dynamically allocated objects in m_member_A vector. You actually dont need to call:

```
m_member_A.clear();
```

std::vector will free its memory on its own.

If you can use C++11, then I would suggest changing to shared_ptr:

```
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> m_member_A
```

now you dont need to free memory on your own.