# Destructor called on std::vector<Class type> invalidating for_each

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I've been doing some reading about `delete[]`, `new[]`, [what-is-the-rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), 
[deallocating-objects-stored-in-a-vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808480/deallocating-objects-stored-in-a-vector), [delete-vector-class-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534373/delete-vector-class-member) and encountering an

> Exception thrown: read access violation.

I have defined a base class

```
class Person
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    static int cur_id;
public:
    Person() {}
    Person(std::string new_name, int new_age) : name(new_name), age(new_age) { cur_id += 1; }
    virtual ~Person() {}
    void setname(std::string name) { this->name = name; }
    std::string getname() { return name; }
    int getage() { return age; }
    void setage(int age) { this->age = age; }
    int get_id() { return cur_id; }

    virtual void getdata(void) = 0;
    virtual void putdata(void) = 0;
};
```

Derived class

```
class Professor : private Person
{
private:
    int publications;
    Professor* prof;
public:
    Professor() {}
    Professor(std::string new_name, int new_age, int new_pubs) : Person(new_name, new_age) { this->publications = new_pubs; }
    ~Professor() override { delete prof; }
    void getdata() override 
    {
        std::vector<std::string> prof_input = get_input();
        std::cout << prof_input[0] << "\n";
        std::cout << std::stoi(prof_input[1]) << "\n";
        std::cout << std::stoi(prof_input[2]) << "\n";
        prof = new Professor(prof_input[0], std::stoi(prof_input[1]), std::stoi(prof_input[2]));
    }
    void putdata() override 
    {
        std::cout << prof->getname() << " " << prof->getage() << " " << prof->publications << " " << prof->get_id();
    }
};
```

and have defined main

```
int main()
{
    int size; 

    std::cin >> size;

    std::cin.ignore();

    Professor* prof = new Professor();

    std::vector<Professor> prof_vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int which;
        std::cin >> which;
        std::cin.ignore();

        switch (which)
        {
        case 1: 
        {
            prof->getdata();
            prof_vec.push_back(*prof);
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        {
            // something else
        }
        break;
        }
    }

    for (auto prof : prof_vec)
    {
        prof.putdata();
    }  <<< ------------------- Things so south here

    delete prof;

    fgetc(stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

What I figured was happening is (assuming only one element in the vector), once the call to `putdata()` exited the block, the destructor call `delete prof` occurs followed by

> this->prof was 0xCDCDCDCD.

I'm attempting to delete an object that doesn't exist.  If I want to be sure to properly `delete`, what should I be doing to ensure no memory leaks even with such a simple example?

Comment: If you really want to ensure no memory leaks in a modern C++ way, use a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) (link pretty old, c++11's smart pointer is named `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: @spectras I entirely agree with you.  My example is contrived for learning proper memory  management but I would use `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` with `std::make_unique()` or `std::make_shared()` in a hearbeat

Comment: Okay. Well in your program, `for (auto prof : prof_vec)` makes a temporary copy of each professor while iterating. It's possible because you didn't disable copy constructor and your class has a default constructor and only trivial non-static members. Except the compiler-generated copy constructor simply copies the pointer, which is bound to go wrong. Use `for (auto & prof : prof_vec)` if you don't want to copy them. And disable that copy constructor you'll also catch the push_back() copy.

Comment: Please read what a [mcve]. The vast majority of this code is completely irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @spectras So `Class& Class(Class const& copy) = delete` ?

Comment: @Barry Will do and thank you.  I get dinged for showing minimal examples using contrived constructs and people end up asking for more code so I tend be a bit more on the verbose side.

Comment: You should not have `Professor* prof;` as a class member of Professor, that makes no sense at all . Instead the `getdata()` function should initialize the current instance.

Answer (score 4):

You're violating the [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

```
class Professor : private Person
{
private:
    Professor* prof;
public:
    // ...
    ~Professor() override { delete prof; }
};
```

If you provide one of the special member functions, you should provide *all* of the special member functions. In this case, your copy constructor just member-wise copies the `Professor*` and now you have two different objects trying to delete the same pointer.

Prefer the rule of 0:

```
class Professor : private Person
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Professor> prof;
public:
    // ...
    ~Professor() = default;
};
```

Comment: @M.M Yeah probably, didn't even notice that they were the same type! Just saw the lack of special members and my inner siren went off.

Answer (score 2):

The member `Professor* prof` is not initialized in the constructor `Professor()`, and is only initialized in `getdata();`

When the code goes to case 2, if there is not any call to `getdata()`, then the `prof` is left uninitialized.

The `0xCDCDCDCD` indicates an uninitialized value in debug mode.